# Sorting the array with Custom Key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of one structure like below

```
$array1 = array(
[123] => array('1'=>'1','2'=>'3'),
[345] => array('1'=>'3','2'=>'5'),
[789] => array('1'=>'1','2'=>'5'),
[567] => array('1'=>'6','2'=>'5'),
);
```

and another array structure as `$array2 = array(567,345,789,123);`

Now i want to sort this one with php sort function, i mean sort the first array with second one to looks like the desired output something like
below

```
$array1 = array(
[567] => array('1'=>'6','2'=>'5'),
[345] => array('1'=>'3','2'=>'5'),
[789] => array('1'=>'1','2'=>'5'),
[123] => array('1'=>'1','2'=>'3'),
);
```

I want to get these desired result with any sorting function which is already exists.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Loop your `$array2` and populate a third array as follows:

```
$array1 = array(
    [123] => array('1'=>'1','2'=>'3'),
    [345] => array('1'=>'3','2'=>'5'),
    [789] => array('1'=>'1','2'=>'5'),
    [567] => array('1'=>'6','2'=>'5'),
);

$array2 = array(567,345,789,123);

$orderedArray = array();
foreach ($array2 as $key) {
    $orderedArray[$key] = $array1[$key];
}
```

And if you want a function:

```
function orderArray($arrayToOrder, $keys) {
    $ordered = array();
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        if (isset($arrayToOrder[$key])) {
             $ordered[$key] = $arrayToOrder[$key];
        }
    }
    return $ordered;
}

$myOrderedArray = orderArray($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 6):

Or you can use `uksort` function of php as

```
uksort($array1, function($a, $b)use($array2) {
    foreach($array2 as $value){
        if($a == $value){
            return 0;
            break;
        }
        if($b == $value){
            return 1;
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://eval.in/387966)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$sortedArray = array_replace(array_flip($array2), $array1);
```

Comment: May I know why this is downvoted?

Comment: Actually, this seems like the simplest approach. +1