# Sort array based on user-defined order of index

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, php-7.3

I would like to restructure the array (not traditional sort), based on providing the wanted index order, e.g. [1,7,4].
Below just sorts ascending order based on value.

**wanted result:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => c
    [4] => b
    [7] => a
)
```

---

**My code:**

```
$array = [];

$array[4] = "b";
$array[1] = "c";
$array[7] = "a";

print_r($array);

echo "\n\n" . "Sort ascending..." . "\n\n";
asort($array);
print_r($array);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [4] => b
    [1] => c
    [7] => a
)


Sort ascending...

Array
(
    [7] => a
    [4] => b
    [1] => c
)
```

Comment: Why don't you use simple loops to achieve this?

Comment: You want to sort keys in ascending manner?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting the array with Custom Key in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055645/sorting-the-array-with-custom-key-in-php)

Comment: What do you mean by user defined order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you need to do is build a custom function so you can pass in the sort keys for your custom ordering.  This will take your keys and then pull each key from the array and build a new array with the correct order as desired.

```
$array = [];

$array[4] = "b";
$array[1] = "c";
$array[7] = "a";

function sortByKeyOrder(array $sortOrderKeys, array $arrayToSort){
   $output = [];
   foreach($sortOrderKeys as $index){
     if(isset($arrayToSort[$index])){
         $output[$index] = $arrayToSort[$index];
     }
   }

  return $output;
}

//usage 
sortByKeyOrder([1, 4, 7], $array);
```

Comment: Closest answer. Running it provides error but I do understand the code structure.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: haha i had a small typo in my answer.  The if condition was missing a bracket.  I corrected my answer.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c2c03cbf392e42c86db41af8871522aeb55c2f69  you can review here

Answer (score 1):

please, test with the rsort

```
$array = [];

$array[4] = "b";
$array[1] = "c";
$array[7] = "a";

print_r($array); 

echo "\n\n" . "Sort ascending..." . "\n\n";
rsort($array);  //sort descending
print_r($array);
```

Comment: rsort sort per index, I want to define the order of the index.

Comment: maybe with arsort(),  sort associative arrays in descending order, according to the value

Answer (score 0):

`ksort` is sorting items in array by `key`

```php
ksort($array);

Array
(
    [1] => c
    [4] => b
    [7] => a
)
```

Comment: Isn't a SORT_NUMERIC flag necessary?

Comment: No, it's not gonna sort `4, 1, 11` like this: `1, 11, 4` but like this: `1, 4, 11`. So this flag is not necessary

Comment: Makes sense.....

Answer (score 0):

Is this how you are expecting?

```
//-- your array
$array = [];

$array[4] = "b";
$array[1] = "c";
$array[7] = "a";

print_r( $array );

//-- the order you want to sort
$input_index = [1,4,7];

//-- new array
$new_array = [];
foreach( $input_index as $i )
{
    $new_array[ $i ] = $array[ $i ];
}

print_r( $new_array );
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [4] => b 
    [1] => c 
    [7] => a 
) 

Array ( 
    [1] => c 
    [4] => b 
    [7] => a 
)
```